# Cannot open backup device 'XXXX'. Operating system error 32(The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-restore

I am trying to restore a database using a script but I'm encountering this error

```
Msg 3201, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot open backup device 'XXXX'. Operating system error 32(The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.).
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

When I tried to restore the .bak file using Database > Restore Database, it doesn't have the Database name, .log file and .mdf file.

I'd like to know what is causing this.

Comment: go to restore>files and make sure you are giving path of your database's ldf and mdf file in restored as tab

Comment: Can you show your script?